# SQL: how to select something using information from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two SQL tables.

In the first table, each line has (amongst other fields that are irrelevant to the question) a `score` and a `category_id` field

The second table (`categories`) is a table listing all the possible categories to which an element in the first table can belong.

I'd like to do the following SQL request :

```
SELECT category_name, ( ??? ) AS category_score
FROM categories
ORDER BY category_score DESC
```

where `???` = `the sum of the scores of all the elements in table 1 that belong to the category`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT   category_name, SUM(score) AS category_score
FROM     categories c
JOIN     element e ON c.category_id = e.category_id
GROUP BY category_name 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about `group by`, I'll look into it. Just a quick question though, I don't get the `ORDER BY 2 DESC` part ? Why isn't it `GROUP BY category_score DESC` for instance ?

Comment: @Malimalo The `group by` clause breaks up the result to groups, so that aggregate functions (like `sum`) can be applied to each unique value of `category_name` independently. Once this is done, the result still needs to be sorted, which is done with the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was actually the `2` in the `order by` that I didn't get. But I did what I should have done before asking, googled it and got my answer (that it meant `order by the second element of select line`) really quickly. Thank you for your help ;)